# Open Google links into new tab

Tags: java, selenium

I want to open Google search results into new tab. I tried this code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
        searchBox.submit();

        System.out.println("Current Url: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3.r a")));

        List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"));

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        {
            String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);

            System.out.println("Google result " + results.get(i).getText());
        }
```

So far the code opens empty tabs and prints the name of the search results. How I can open the links from the searh results?

Comment: I'm trying your code.. it just opening 11 new tab with same url like https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/... so basically what is the fail here???

Comment: I need to open the links from Google result into each tab.

Comment: You means every results which is displays in main page open in new tab??

Comment: Just change this line `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);` to  this `results.get(i).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);` and it's working fine for me..

Comment: Correct. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change below line inside `loop` :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNew‌​Tab);
```

to

```
results.get(i).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

it's working...:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/WorkSpace/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
        searchBox.submit();

        System.out.println("Current Url: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3.r a")));

        List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"));

        for (WebElement ele : results) {
            String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
            ele.sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);


        }
```